# How to keep Auth-Cookie and (ASP.NET) Session in sync?

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

We are working on a ASP.NET vNext project and we are implementing simple cookie-based authentication.

We thought about using the auth-cookie just to verify the user is authenticated. It's created like this:

```
HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync();
```

The user-object itself would be saved to the session-cache (ISession).

- Is this a practise one could use or are we thinking about this the entirely the wrong way?
- If the basic idea is correct, how do we keep the auth-cookie and the session in sync? (An unauthenticated user with a user-object in the session-cache would be bad)

Note that not only the user-object should be stored in the session. There is a bunch of information that should be stored there (only if the user is authenticated).

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your requirements is it an option for you to use [Cookie middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html) to persist the user between requests and use [Claims-based authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html) to persist additional info you want to remember about the user?

So in the Startup class in the Configure method you'd add the cookie middleware for instance like:

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            options.LoginPath = new PathString(@"/account/login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(@"/account/accessdenied");

        });
```

And then in ConfigureServices you can set the claims you require like for instance this:

```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber"));
});
```

Please consider the links for complete documentation about how to set this up.